# Spring cloud stream merge responses from two different functions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, event-driven

I'm trying to use spring cloud stream to solve the following problem:

[image]

I have a class that calls two separated functions (Function A and B), both of those functions must work in parallel if the Function A finishes it must call the Function C, the same happens if Function B finish but this will call Function D, then I need to wait for Function C and Function D to finish and merge both responses in a single response, and then return this merged response object to the starting class that must be waiting to get that response.

The problems I have are:

- How do I call Function C to pass the Function A response?
- How to wait until Function C and Function D finish and get their responses in Function E?
- How to wait for the response of Function E in the controller, I'm using `streamBridge.send` which to start Function A and Function B at the same time.

I'm using

- `spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3`
- `spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit` **Required**

I cannot use `Kafka` **Required**

**Sample code**

*ServiceClass*

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ServiceClass {

    @NonNull
    private final StreamBridge streamBridge;

    @Override
    protected MergedResponse execute(Input input) {
        var send1 = streamBridge.send("functionA-in-0", input);
        var send2 = streamBridge.send("functionB-in-0", input);

        //TODO: Wait for Function E response object
    }
}
```

*Function A*

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class FunctionAClass{

    @Bean
    public Function<Input, OutputFunctionA> functionA() {
        return input -> {
            //TODO: Invoke Function C to pass OutputFunctionA object
            return OutputFunctionA.builder.build();
        };
    }
}
```

I don't mind using `Supplier` or `Consumer` instead of `Function`.

**Edit**
Hi, @Oleg Zhurakousky thanks for your help, to answer your question my problem is: I have to create a REST endpoint that consume `N` different third-party REST endpoints (two at first, async is a must as it will be too slow to process every request sequentially) I don't need all the data from them, just a few fields to build a common object. I'm planning to used `streamBridge` to start the first two functions that will to build the required request for each third-party, then a function to invoke each of their endpoints, then a function to build a common object with each response, and finally a function that collects the commons objects and send them in the response of my service. Let me know if you have another question.

Regards.

Comment: You are describing your design to a business problem. It would be much better if you actually  describe such problem so we could potentially discuss and suggest a better design within the context of s-c-stream. So all I can answer at this point is that you can use function composition to address sequential hand off from one function to another and then have and aggregator function at the end with some synchronization mechanism. But as I said, i would rather know the actual business problem to be able to suggest something more concrete.

Comment: Hi Oleg Zhurakousky, I want to build a Rest Controller that allows me to start a flow like pattern (each step of the flow will be a spring cloud binding function), the flow starts one or more async tasks and these tasks (when finished) could also start another task to pass the data to the next step of the flow, and finally the ontroller who started the flow will wait for the result of the flow (which is the result of the last task), on my example I need to merge in the last task the results from two differents tasks to return the data to the controller (Service Class in my example), thanks.

Comment: Sorry, you are still describing your design. What I wanted is something like: "I have data that is coming in from two different sources. The entry point is REST. The data from two sources needs to be processed independently and then the result of each processing needs to be aggregated into a single response etc. . .". All I am trying to determine is if you even have a case for s-c-function or s-c-stream

Comment: Hi, @OlegZhurakousky thanks for your help, could you please check my edits on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of points.

1. Since you are introducing a synchronization point you will have in the end a blocking call no matter what you try since synchronization (such as your aggregation requirement) would have to wait, for two responses, correlate then etc. On top there is an issue of state that you are going to deal with and how to recover such state in the event of a system crash during aggregation.
2. Aggregation is not really a use case for s-c-stream so we don't have a framework-based support for it. I would consider using Spring Integration framework to create pipelines for two+ different endpoints, aggregate then using [Aggregator pattern](aggregator pattern support ) and then use StreamBridge to send data out to target destination.